# Trying to get my restart button to stay idle for 2 - 3 seconds

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have created a game similar to Flappy Bird. I have set up a function so that when the hero dies a restartScene is called. When touched this restarts the game so the user can continue to play.

My question is, is it possible to make it so there is a 2-3 seconds delay before the user can click restart?

```
func restartScene(){

    self.removeAllChildren()
    self.removeAllActions()
    died = false
    gameStarted = false
    score = 0
    createScene()

}

 override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if gameStarted == false{

        gameStarted = true

  for touch in touches{
        let location = touch.location(in: self)

        if died == true{


            restartScene()
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: where is this code? In an SKScene, or a custom button class using touchesBegan? Which brings up the next question, how do you want the logic to look, in terms of where/what/how etc.

Comment: I am calling it in didBegin  contact

I just want it to look how it looks atm! Just with a delay so the user can not die and restart game within 0.1 of a second.

Comment: WHERE? In the SKScene, or in the button?

Comment: SKScene I think? @Confused

Comment: Ok... this is kind of important, as the two ways of handling interaction (in a thing as opposed to in a coordinating scene) are substantially different in flow and thought of the architecture and design

Comment: I've added more code to the bottom of my initial question if that helps

Comment: No. Not really. where is the code, in your project? Which file is it in? which class is it in that file?

Comment: It is in a swift file.

class SceneTwo: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
I have added a heap more code to my initial question.

Comment: Which funciton is called when you click `restartButton`?

Comment: Im so sorry, I've made a mistake.. I was wondering why everyones answers were confusing me. Probably because the question confused them. My restart button is actually just an image that pops up when the player has died. When the player has died the func restartScene() is called inside of the for touch in touches. I think this might make it easier to understand.

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: Why do you want to prevent them from immediately starting again?

Comment: So they can't restart the scene straight away..? I want it have a delay of 2-3 seconds before they can touch, or they touch the screen and it takes 2 seconds for it to restart.

Comment: Yes, I get that's the mechanic you're after, but why?

Comment: What do you mean why? Because I want it to

Comment: If there is no delay it is like the player never died, they just continue tapping away there has to be some pause, in my opinion

Comment: ?? OK  just say I tell you "I want to annoy them and I think it adds to the experience" How the hell is that information going to help my code? It is completely irrelevant, all I want to do is add a delay. Im really not sure where you going with this. This is a website that helps people create their ideas in code, not judge them on the ideas of there code. My game is not the impossible game, nor the super hexagon.

Comment: There are two options, you've only considered one: preventing operation of the button. The other is to permit operation of the button, then do a pause, via launch countdown. 3, 2, 1... GO! etc. If you weren't so busy telling me what this site is all about you might have spent a few seconds to watch how other masocore games start.

Comment: A third, worse, option, is to hide the button for a period of time. But the less said about that, the better.

Comment: @Confused, he doesn't want the button to be operational during a transition, there is nothing wrong with that

Answer (score 1):

Use an `SKAction` at the end of your createButton to perform a delay:

Scenario 1, you are using `SKScene` to handle all touch events (this is what you have to be doing since restartButton is an `SKSpriteNode`):

```
let enable = SKAction.run({[unowned self] in self.restartButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false})

restartButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true //This actually disables the button because the touch handler will not be called by scene, but instead the individual button. 
//The individual button will have no touch code associated with it, so nothing will happen

restartButton.run(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.wait(duration:2),enable]), withKey:"waitingToEnable")
```

Scenario 2, you are using restartButton as a custom class:

```
let enable = SKAction.run({[unowned self] in self.restartButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true})

restartButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false //This disables the button because the touch handler will not be called by individual button, and instead will go to whatever is touch enabled under it. 
restartButton.run(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.wait(duration:2),enable]), withKey:"waitingToEnable")
```

In your particular case, here is how I would write it:

```
func createButton(){

    restartButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "restart")
    restartButton.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2)
    restartButton.zPosition = 10
    restartButton.setScale(1.2)
    restartButton.name = "Restart"
    restartButton.setScale(1.5)
    self.addChild(restartButton)

    let enable = SKAction.run({[unowned self] in self.restartButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false})

    restartButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true //This actually disables the button because the touch handler will not be called by scene, but instead the individual button. 
    //The individual button will have no touch code associated with it, so nothing will happen

    let waitAndEnable = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.wait(duration:2),enable])
    let fadeIn = SKAction.fadeIn(withDuration: 1.5)
    let runConcurrently = SKAction.group([waitAndEnable,fadeIn])
    restartButton.run(runConcurrently)

    highScoreLabel.text = "High Score: \(UserDefaults().integer(forKey: "HIGHSCORE"))"
    highScoreLabel.fontColor = UIColor.white
    highScoreLabel.fontSize = 20
    highScoreLabel.position = CGPoint(x: 80, y: 20)
    highScoreLabel.zPosition = 6

    livesLabel.position = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width / 5.4, y: 30)
    livesLabel.text = "Lives: \(lives)"
    livesLabel.zPosition = 5
    livesLabel.fontSize = 20
    livesLabel.fontColor = UIColor.black
    self.addChild(livesLabel)
    livesLabel.zPosition = 10
}
```

It looks like you are not handling the touchesBegan properly.  You have it set up to where the user touches anywhere on the scene, the game will restart.

You need to target the specific node to ensure that this happens.

I have added the touchesBegan changes to meet your needs.  You will have to name your game scene what is in the case statement to get this to work.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

  for touch in touches{
    let location = touch.location(in: self)
    let node = nodeAtPoint(location)
    switch(node.name)
    {
      case "Restart":
        if died = true{
          restartScene()
        }
      case "GameScene": //maybe we want to make this a button?
        gameStarted = true //who cares about a branch statement
      default:()
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: that's also a pretty clutch usage of `[unowned self]` props

Comment: It is definitely not piggybacking, since 1st, your isUserInteractionEnabled logic is backwards, and 2 the code itself is self explanitory (Athough you did catch me on using swift 2, so I updated to swift 3).  It is quite simple.  You record a unique action that enables the state of the button, place the button into a disabled state, and run the action to get back into an enable state

Comment: `self explanatory` doesn't cut it or books would just be code ;)

and how is my code backwards? I had to edit your answer because you had false backwards

Comment: That is the way you have to use it to avoid retain cycles.  since restartButton is inside of scene, and run works only when a scene is alive, it is safe to say that self will exist without it having to be a weak reference

Comment: `restartButton.userInteractionEnabled = true //This will mean the touch handler will not be called by scene, but instead the individual button
restartButton.run(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.wait(duration:2),enable]), withKey:"waitingToEnable")`

I'm the one with the backwards logic :P

Comment: It is not my duty to explain what every method does, this is not a tutorial site.  I did not use any generic or random variable names, so self explanatory does cut it on SO

Comment: /facepalm my job as a tutor would be a lot easier if I never had to explain anything :D

Comment: 1) apparently you do not understand how `isUserInteractionEnabled` works.  Every `SKNode` has its own set of touch calls,  so unless you are extending `SKSpriteNode` to handle touch events (Which is not advised in this scenario), nothing is going to happen because the sprite will absorb the touch, meaning the scene touch event will never get called. 2)This is a Q&A site, so basic functionality should not have to be explained, we are allowed to assume the user has some programming experience and knows how to find other resources to understand the basic functionalities they do not understand.

Comment: Hi, I've added this to my code but it doesn't seem to add a delay. I can still tap to restart the scene immediately. Am I meant to add something else when I call this action or should calling the whole function be sufficient? Thanks for your detailed answer though! @Knight0fDragon

Comment: I am using it as a custom class btw Ive added in my initial question what I've taken from your answer - not sure if I've done it correctly.

Comment: Hey I've added a heap more code to the bottom of my initial question, hope some of that can help.

Comment: Ive edited my question, Im sorry I think I sent everyone on a wild goose chase! The button does not actually exist it is just an image that pops up. Then if the user touches the screen the function restartScene() is called

Comment: @niX, my answer still stands.  I am treating your restartScene like you have talked about.  Your problem is if you touch anywhere on the screen you are restarting your game,  can't do that.  You need to add `touch.nodeAtPoint(location)` to get the node you are touching, and check to see if that is the restartScene image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130991/discussion-between-knight0fdragon-and-nix).

Answer (score 0):

I usually make my own timer and put it in .update() for things that don't need precise control... there are Actions and Delta-Time functions for that. I remade this answer to be simpler than my previous:

Below, we set up a namespace for a few variables, enum timer, and use that to update our clock, and also use it as a logic state for whether or not we should act on a `restartButton` click.

Our framerate is assumed to be 60, so update is called 60 timers per second.. thus we add a "tick" each time, and after 60 ticks we know that there has been a second. This isn't exact, and on games lower than 60 framerate you would need to do some delta-time math to get the timings right (or use another approach)

But in this simple example, I'm keeping it simple to a basic timer, that way you can have explicit control over everything in your scene.

Basically, once we reach 3 seconds it will be time.toPlay = true making the conditional statement "true" thus allowing us to execute the `click()` function you have created. Afterwords, it will reset `time.toPlay` to false, so that way if you click the button again nothing will happen:

This essentially gives you 3 seconds of not being allowed to touch the button, as it fades in and what-not. Personally IMO, 2 seconds would be better than 3, especially since your fadein is 1.5seconds:

```
// In GameScene field area:
enum time {
  static var ticks   = 0
  static var seconds = 0
  static var toPlay  = false
}

// In update():
time.ticks += 1
if time.ticks   >= 60 { time.seconds += 1; time.ticks  = 0    }
if time.seconds >= 2  { time.seconds =  0; time.toPlay = true }

// In the code block where you detect restartButton:
if time.toPlay { 
  // Call your restartGame function here:
  // ...
} else { return }
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use a function to wait some seconds and then call the function createButton()

---

You can use like this

```
self.perform(#selector(self.createButton), with: nil, afterDelay: 2.0)
```

Then, it will be called 2s later.

Comment: perform is not a good option to use in Sprite Kit.  Sprite Kit has its own set of timers that do not correlate with the system timers, so in instances when you pause the scene, the timer will still fire

Comment: this is a cool option. I don't think the world will end if the accuracy is not 100% for something like this

Comment: It will end if you some how the scene is destroyed before the timer fires, it will literally kill the app

Comment: There is `best practice`, and there is `best not do this`  Not doing `best practice` can lead to ineffecient coding,  not doing `best not do this` can lead to code crashes. Better to teach programmers to not do things they shouldn't be doing in the first place BEFORE they make a habit of it.

Comment: I'm going to use this in my code because it seems pretty handy, especially if put in a thread :P I could have a thread with a `while 0 == 0` and just have all sorts of timing control. neat.